# Show that $ \int_I x^{-\frac{1}{4}} $sin$ x \;dx \leq \pi^{\frac{3}{4}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

> Let $I=[0,\pi]$. Show that $\displaystyle \int_I x^{-\frac{1}{4}} $sin$ x \;dx \leq \pi^{\frac{3}{4}}$.

My Work:

I think this is an application of Holders inequality. But any positive power of $ x^{-\frac{1}{4}}$ is not integrable over $I$. So I was stuck. Can anyone please give me a hint for the start.

Comment: Know that `$\sin x$` produces $\sin x$ :) Here's a quick little LaTeX guide different from the MathJax one everyone recommends: http://users.dickinson.edu/~richesod/latex/latexcheatsheet.pdf

Comment: You have guessed Holder ?! :-) Nice!! It shouldn't hold you back anymore .. use Cauchy-Schwarz ! :)

Comment: $$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x^{1/4}}\,dx \le \left(\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2 x\,dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{x^{1/2}}\,dx\right)^{1/2} = \pi^{3/4}$$

Comment: @r9m: Don't you know that Cauchy Schwarz is a particular case of Holder's? :) anyway thanks!

Comment: @Mathi welcome ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hölder's inequality like this: $$\int_I x^{-1/4}\sin x\,{\rm d}x \leq \left(\int_I (x^{-1/4})^{4/3}\,{\rm d}x\right)^{3/4}\left(\int_I\sin^4 x\, {\rm d}x\right)^{1/4} \leq \left(\int_I x^{-1/3}\,{\rm d}x\right)^{3/4}.$$